# Moved and symlinked usr

Tags: networking, partitioning

I foolishly moved usr on my Ubuntu 12.04 system

I did:

```
cp -rp /usr /home/usr
ln -s /home/usr /usr
```

Now networking has stopped working.
I don't know if anything else is broken (the launcher lost things, but that's easy to fix)
Can I recover from this without repartioning and starting over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that nothing got severly screwed during the original operation, reversing the process should move things back to normal if a reboot is applied afterwards:

```
unlink /usr
cp -rp /home/usr /usr
```

If the above resolves the issue, you can safely delete /home/usr

Comment: Are you sure?  I am assuming there is a hard link somewhere.  Reversing won't fix that.  My current theory is a delete-install of the networking package.  Which name I should remember because I broke it recently and searching hasn't come up with it.

Comment: That theory failed.  Will try copying back.